# How to retrieve all available environment variables?

Tags: environment-variables, ocaml

Is there a way in OCaml to retrieve all available environment variables?

The OCaml stdlib provides the following in the `Sys` module:

```
val getenv : string -> string
```

But it only show if an env var is available. Is there a way to list all variables in the environment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use [`Unix.environment`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html#VALenvironment) from the `unix` library (distributed with the OCaml system). Example:

```
>   ocaml unix.cma
        OCaml version 4.03.0

# Unix.environment ();;
- : string array = ...
```